# How to create JSON structure from a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a JSON structure from a pyspark dataframe. I have below columns in my dataframe - batch_id, batch_run_id, table_name, column_name, column_datatype, last_refresh_time, refresh_frequency, owner

I want it in below JSON structure -

```
{
"GeneralInfo": {
    "DataSetID": "xxxx1234Abcsd", 
    "Owner" : ["test1@email.com", "test2@email.com", "test3@email.com"]
    "Description": "", 
    "BuisnessFunction": "", 
    "Source": "", 
    "RefreshRate": "Weekly",
    "LastUpdate": "2020/10/15", 
    "InfoSource": "TemplateInfo"
  },
  "Tables": [
    {
      "TableName": "Employee",
      "Columns" : [
               { "ColumnName" : "EmployeeID",
                  "ColumnDataType": "int"
               },
               { "ColumnName" : "EmployeeName",
                  "ColumnDataType": "string"
               }
            ]
    }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to assign the values in JSON string through dataframe column indexes but it is giving me an error as "Object of Type Column is not JSON serializable". I have used like below -

```
{
"GeneralInfo": {
    "DataSetID": df["batch_id"], 
    "Owner" : list(df["owner"])
    "Description": "", 
    "BuisnessFunction": "", 
    "Source": "", 
    "RefreshRate": df["refresh_frequency"],
    "LastUpdate": df["last_update_time"], 
    "InfoSource": "TemplateInfo"
  },
  "Tables": [
    {
      "TableName": df["table_name"],
      "Columns" : [
               { "ColumnName" : df["table_name"]["column_name"],
                  "ColumnDataType": df["table_name"]["column_datatype"]
               } 
     
            ]
     }
  }
}
```

Sample Data -
[image: Sample Data]

Please help me on this, I have newly started coding in Pyspark.

Comment: Could you please paste sample dataframe?

Comment: @MohanaBC I've updated my post, please check. Thanks

Comment: @MohanaBC - Did you check?

Comment: Yeah, But Not getting single JSON element as you expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried getting JSON format from the sample data which you provided, output format is not matching exactly as you expected. You can improvise the below code further.

We can use toJSON function to convert dataframe to JSON format. Before calling toJSON function we need to use array(), struct functions by passing required columns to match JSON format as required.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').getOrCreate()

in_values = [
    (123, '123abc', 'Employee', 'Employee_id', 'int', '21/05/15', 'Weekly',
     ['test1@gmail.com', 'test1@gmail.com', 'test3@gmail.com']),
    (123, '123abc', 'Employee', 'Employee_name', 'string', '21/05/15', 'Weekly',
     ['test1@gmail.com', 'test1@gmail.com', 'test3@gmail.com'])
]

cols = ["batch_id", "batch_run_id", "table_name", "column_name", "column_datatype",
        "last_update_time", "refresh_frequency", "Owner"]


df = spark.createDataFrame(in_values).toDF(*cols)\
    .selectExpr("*","'' Description", "'' BusinessFunction", "'TemplateInfo' InfoSource", "'' Source")

list1 = [df["batch_id"].alias("DataSetID"), df["Owner"], df["refresh_frequency"].alias("RefreshRate"),
         df["last_update_time"].alias("LastUpdate"), "Description", "BusinessFunction","InfoSource", "Source"]

list2 = [df["table_name"].alias("TableName"),df["column_name"].alias("ColumnName"),
         df["column_datatype"].alias("ColumnDataType")]

df.groupBy("batch_id") \
    .agg(collect_set(struct(*list1))[0].alias("GeneralInfo"),
         collect_list(struct(*list2)).alias("Tables")).drop("batch_id") \
    .toJSON().foreach(print)

# outputs JSON --->
    '''
     {
   "GeneralInfo":{
         "DataSetID":123,
         "Owner":[
            "test1@gmail.com",
            "test1@gmail.com",
            "test3@gmail.com"
         ],
         "RefreshRate":"Weekly",
         "LastUpdate":"21/05/15",
         "Description":"",
         "BusinessFunction":"",
         "InfoSource":"TemplateInfo",
         "Source":""
      },
   "Tables":[
      {
         "TableName":"Employee",
         "ColumnName":"Employee_id",
         "ColumnDataType":"int"
      },
      {
         "TableName":"Employee",
         "ColumnName":"Employee_name",
         "ColumnDataType":"string"
      }
   ]
}
'''
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I see that you've hardcoded the column names to create the lists. Any dynamic way to handle this rather than hardcoding?

Comment: Also, 
`{ "GeneralInfo": {     "DataSetID": "xxxx1234Abcsd",     "Owner" : ["test1@email.com", "test2@email.com", "test3@email.com"]     "Description": "",     "BuisnessFunction": "",     "Source": "",     "RefreshRate": "Weekly",     "LastUpdate": "2020/10/15", "InfoSource": "TemplateInfo" }`
would be under {} not []

Comment: We can dynamically generate list using generators, we need to consider column renaming also here as your json format has different names.

Comment: from [] i.e array to {} i.e struct, we can change that. Let me know if you are okay with second part "Tables":[....] ?

Comment: updated the code to get only struct. Is column rename like table_name to TableName required? or will data have column name as TableName?

Comment: That's fine. Many thanks for all your support @MohanaBC. Cheers!

Comment: @MohanaBC Is this possible somehow to combine `collect_list(struct(*list2))` with some function to decide if include based on value inside? E.g. Include in `Tables` if value is equal to `Employee`, not `Employer`

Comment: You can try using when and otherwise function.